# Why is Facebook throwing an error when I edit App Domains?

Tags: dns, facebook-apps

I registered a .cc domain name (www.kreative.cc). But when I type "kreative.cc" in the App Domains field in the application manager I got an error

> Erro There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

I did test other urls and they're all right. 
I've been trying for a couple of days. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [facebook graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) to write your [app settings](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/), seems that facebook is not validating the input this way. here is a simple example in php:

```
<?php

include 'Zend/Http/Client.php';

$http = new Zend_Http_Client('https://graph.facebook.com/MY_APP_ID');
$http->setMethod('POST');
$http->setParameterPost(array(

        'access_token'                  =>      'MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        'app_domains'                   =>      array('mydomain.cc'),
        'website_url'                   =>      'http://mydomain.cc',
        'page_tab_url'                  =>      'http://mydomain.cc',
        'secure_page_tab_url'   =>      'https://mydomain.cc',
));
$response = $http->request()->getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the Apps Domain field empty while filling up the rest of the fields - be it Page Tab of Facebook App. That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I`m following the Developers Bug Report http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/130468767129410

If you fill App Domain Name with the site IP you'll got success. Ex: `http://50.23.134.34` instead of http://www.kreative.cc.